# jquery to Loop through specific form input fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to loop through specific form input fields in a grid and apply the "disabled" attribute.  All of these particular input field name and id attributes start with "dept_" followed by a number. For example:

```
dept_10
dept_11
dept_789
```

I can cut down on processing since I only want fields that do not have the "disabled" attribute already applied, which some will.

What would any jquery look like to accomplish that?

Comment: what do you mean start with "dept_" ? the text,  the name, the id or what?

Comment: both name and id attributes start with "dept_".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use `[attr^=]` selector to filter starting with, and `:enabled` to filter not disabled inputs, then just disable each one:

```
$("input[id^='dept_']:enabled").each(function(){
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can grab all form inputs, filter by ID (or name), and then disable them.

```
$('#the-form').find('input').filter(':enabled').filter(function() {
    return /^dept_/.test($(this).attr('id'));
}).prop('disabled', true);
```

If you want to match any input-like element (e.g., `<textarea>`), you can use `.find(':input')` instead of `.find('input')`.

Also, if you want to be very strict about the format of the ID, you could use `/^dept_[\d]+$/.test(...)`.